# Accessing data from the table - JSON/Java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I need to access to the "mid" but I need to sort it somehow, so I need to get the "code" and then get the "mid" value.

Can you help me with this, I have no idea how to refer to that.

Here is what I have:

```
public void onSuccess(String response) {

    Log.i("CHACHING", "HTTP Sucess");

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONObject ratesObject = jonObj.getJSONObject("rates");

        String gbpcode = ratesObject.getString("code");
        Double gbpRate = ratesObject.getDouble(gbpcode."mid");
        Log.i("CHACHING", "GBP: " + gbpRate);
        //  Log.i("CHACHING", "EUR: " + eurRate);

        Double usds = Double.valueOf(usdValue.getText().toString());
        Double gbps = usds * gbpRate;
        // Double euros = usds * eurRate;
        gbpValue.setText("GBP: " + String.valueOf(gbps));

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and the json looks like this

http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/A/?format=json

Answer (score 0):

The json received is list of json objects(json array) and in each json object "rates" is another json Array.

So, in order to access mid.

```
public void onSuccess(String response) { Log.i("CHACHING", "HTTP Sucess");

        try {
    JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(response);
    JSONObject jsonObj=jsonArr.getJSONObject(0);
    //this jsonObj holds the first jsonObject of your response

    JSONArray rateList = jonObj.getJSONArray("rates");
    //rateList has the list of rates you obtained

    //NOW, to get all mids for this rate list

    for(int i=0;i<rateList.length();i++) {
         JSONObject jO=rateList.getJSONObject(i);
         Double mid=jO.getDouble("mid");
         Double gbpcode = jO.getString("code");
    /*
    your code here
    */
    }   
} catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I am glad I could help. @PiotrSzczepanik